# How to fix Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: react-native, gradle

I am facing this after installing react native image picker when using the npx react-native run-android command.

D:\WEB SAYLANI\React Native CLI\AwesomeProject>npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1222 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
103 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 101 up-to-date
D:\WEB SAYLANI\React Native CLI\AwesomeProject\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [:react-native-image-picker] D:\WEB SAYLANI\React Native CLI\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native-image-picker\android\build\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.imagepicker" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [:react-native-image-picker] D:\WEB SAYLANI\React Native CLI\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native-image-picker\android\build\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
> Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
> or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
> or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.imagepicker" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
D:\WEB SAYLANI\React Native CLI\AwesomeProject\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\WEB SAYLANI\React Native CLI\AwesomeProject
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c react-native run-android

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-01-02T18_04_25_264Z-debug.log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the minSdkversion 21.
You can change it from android/build.gradle directly Open the project go to the android folder and open build.gradle file. In this you can find

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked. Can you tell me why it happened?

Answer (score 0):

In my case

the answer of this error you just need to add the library in your gradle gradle -> gradle.properties

android.enableJetifier=true